# Implicit upcasting question

Tags: c++

I find when writing functions (that use function overloading) that accept either a main class or subclass argument, that often implicit upcasting will occur (the subclass is upcasted as the main class and the main class function called). I don't want this implicit upcasting to occur as it means subtle bugs sneak in and cause problems later on down the line.

I have searched on google for information on this, but there is little coherent information I can make use of and only indirect references to it.

How do I disable, stop or prevent implicit upcasting (and even downcasting) from occurring?

(I can't supply any example code as this is a general problem that occurs from time to time).

No, this isn't to do with methods (I would have specified methods) but functions.

No example code, but pseudo idea:
    void Function(BaseClass &A);
    void Function(SubclassClass &B);

```
Function(ASubclass); //Implicit upcasting occurs, calls BaseClass instead
```

The above situation won't happen conventionally (say that the SubclassClass function gets knocked out/erased), but Subclass will be upcast to the BaseClass for use with the BaseClass function, instead of, say, reporting an error or generating a warning - either would be helpful as I don't want implicit upcasting to occur.

Please don't confuse upcasting with non-virtual method calls.

Comment: "I can't supply ..."  I bet you could if you tried, and the quality of the responses would be much higher as a result. General questions receive general answers; specific questions receive specific answers.

Comment: A code example showing your problem, will help answering this tremendously

Comment: Most likely that your design is simply not correct. A derived class has to behave "as if" it was a base class when addressed through the base, so those "subtle bugs" are probably the result of a violation of this promise.

Comment: @KerrekSB: A derived class would not behave `as if` it was a Base class if derivation is `private` and you could disallow implicit conversion.

Comment: @Als: Right, should have said "publicly derived class", good point. I guess you could disallow the conversion, but it might still pay to think about the design if this conversion is causing problems.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, well That's true I mention so in my answer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Base
{    
};

class Derived1:public Base
{ 
};

class Derived2:private Base
{  
};

void doSomething(Base *ptr)
{
}

int main()
{
  Derived1 *ptr1 = new Derived1;
  Derived2 *ptr2 = new Derived2;

  doSomething(ptr1);   //works fine
  doSomething(ptr2);   //Gives error

  return 0;
};
```

**Upcasting:**

A Base class pointer can always point to a derived class object as long as the derived class is `publically` derived from the Base class. Eg: First Function Call.
This upcasting happens **implicitly**.

If the derivation is `private` this upcasting does not happen implicitly and compiler will issue an error.

Though, using `private` inheritance is not the way to achieve this behavior. You should use private inheritance if it suits your design and it will implicitly gaurantee you that upcasting never happens implicitly.

Comment: Excellent. The kind of solution I needed to hear. Would this work if if the base class is protected when derived?

Answer (score 1):

The "up-casting" you are talking about is normal.  The symptoms you are describing sound like you are overloading a non-virtual parents member function.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A 
{
  void sayHello() {cout << "hello from A" << endl;}
};

struct B : public A 
{
  void sayHello() {cout << "hello from B" << endl;}
};

void hello(A& a) 
{
  a.sayHello();
}

int main() 
{
  A a;
  B b;
  hello(a);
  hello(b);
}
```

will produce

```
hello from A
hello from A
```

but if you add the virual to A::sayHello everything works as you would expect

```
struct A 
{
  virtual void sayHello() {cout << "hello from A" << endl;}
};
```

Comment: This isn't the definition of upcasting. Nice try, but these are inheritance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what's going on, but if base class methods are being called when you supply a derived-class object to a method with a base-class parameter type, then either a) you didn't override the base-class method in your derived class, or more likely b) you forget the 'virtual' keyword in your base-class declaration.  Otherwise the derived-class method will be called as expected.

Comment: No methods. Just functions that expect a base and subclass.

Answer (score 0):

@Als your example wont work if derivation is in protected mode.Implicit upcasting is allowed within the derived class only (within methods of the derived class)  because protected members can only be accessed inside the class that derives or base class.