# call non-virtual method of derived class in polymorphic hierarchy of library that can't be modified without down-casting

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern, double-dispatch

Today interviewer told me that **Visitor** pattern & **double dispatch** can be used to call non-virtual method of derived class from 3rd party library which source code can't be accessed/changed (this is what they do in their production code, he said).
For example, in below code they pass reference to `Animal` into `Bar` and call specific methods of classes derived from `Animal` without using `dynamic_cast`. Point is that `dynamic_cast` isn't used anywhere in their implementation. Templates aren't used.

I did rephrased my question to interviewer few times so there's no misunderstanding.

I don't see a way implementing **Visitor** without adding `Accept` method to classes in library that will utilize argument overloading on `Visitor::Visit` by passing `*this` to it.

Is this possible? Or interviewer confused it with other language that probably allow something **C++** doesn't? Because he was emphasizing that **Visitor** and **double dispatch** is used together, whereas AFAIK in **C++** **double dispatch** is **Visitor**, meaning **Visitor** is used to implement **double dispatch**. I hope I didn't lost you. Thanks for your time!

```
import <iostream>;


namespace LibraryCode // can't be changed
{
    class Animal
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Animal() = default;

    public:
        virtual void move() const { std::cout << "Animal: moving!" << std::endl; };

        void breath() const { std::cout << "Animal: breathing!" << std::endl; }
    };

    class Duck : public Animal
    {
    public:
        void move() const override { std::cout << "Duck: flying!" << std::endl; }

        void make_nest() const { std::cout << "Duck: making nest!" << std::endl; }
    };

    class Dolphin : public Animal
    {
    public:
        void move() const override { std::cout << "Dolphin: swimming!" << std::endl; }

        void make_air_bubble() const { std::cout << "Dolphin: making air bubble!" << std::endl; }
    };
}

void Bar(LibraryCode::Animal const& a)
{
    a.breath();
    a.move();

    // w/o using dynamic_cast call make_nest if it's a Duck

    // w/o using dynamic_cast call make_air_bubble if it's a Dolphin
}

int main()
{
    Bar(LibraryCode::Duck{});
    Bar(LibraryCode::Dolphin{});
}
```

Comment: make `Bar` a template?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489067/implicit-upcasting-question

Comment: Probably the library (that you cannot change) has a visit() function with an appropriate visitor. Then you can do dynamic visitation. Either that, or they have (essentially) a variant<Duck, Dolphin> and do a (static) visit on that.

Comment: @AlanBirtles was my first guess to use metaprogramming, but not. Templates aren't used. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @lorro is this common practice for library developers to put virtual `Visit` function in hierarchy? I doubt it was `std::variant` as no templates were involved in solution.

Comment: @SoupEndless It was before variants became preferred (for performance reasons).

Comment: Don't trust any random interviewer. He's a software developer after all. He's probably just as confused as an average visitor of this site.